# Membership Providers and HIPAA Compliance

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider, hipaa

Does anyone know if the provided SQL and Active Directory Membership Providers in ASP.NET 2.0+ are HIPAA compliant?

Clarification:

I understand that HIPAA mandates patient information be secured and that certain policies be put in place to secure access to that information.  Can Microsoft's SQL and AD Membership Providers be used for handling the authentication of users accessing this information?  I expect there to be some policies that need to be established like password length and complexity but is there anything inherit about the way they store information that would invalidate them for the purposes of authorization?  Any gotchas or things to look out for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with them, but in short, yes.  HIPAA is all about standards for securing your data; the standards aren't particularly harsh, so long as you have a way in place to provide for security.  In that way, it's a lot like ISO 9001; so long as you define a security policy and stick with it, you're okay.  The mentioned providers are effectively tools.

That said, you may need to do some additional things with your data to assure that it's only clearly accessible from your application; some level of pre-encryption would probably be appropriate.  Just understand that it probably doesn't need to be HEAVY encryption; very light would do, so long as you're consistent with the application of it.

Comment: HIPAA *is* more about how you secure/protect your data then what you use to do it.  As long as the data is protected, and only accessible by those who are allowed to access it you are okay.

Answer (score 1):

I sure hope it is;)  We currently use the 2.0 Membership Provider with an ADAM LDAP at the health insurance company that I work for. HIPAA and PHI are the name of the game here and this set up went through our legal department.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that out of the box, it is *not* HIPAA compliant.

The way to find out would be to create a new Web Application, with just a default.aspx and maybe a login page. Then click the "ASP.NET Configuration" tool in the Solution Explorer toolbar to launch the configuration application (you can also do this from IIS if your site is hosted there). Set up the defaults, choosing to use the `AspNetSqlProvider` for all features.

This will create an ASPNETDB.MDF in your App_Data folder. Right-click it and choose "Open". This will open it in Server Explorer, where you can look at all the tables that were created.

You'll find that the password is stored hashed in the `aspnet_Membership` table, instead of as plain text. That's a good thing. However, the email address is also stored in the clear. If I remember my HIPAA training from four years ago, that's PII, and should at least *pretend* to be special. As it is, anyone with access to the database could find the email address of any member.

---

**Edit based on update:**

If you're only talking about using them for authentication and authorization, I'd say you're ok. You will need to ignore the email address.

Comment: You can use a custom provider to get around the email address issue.